# React map through multiple arrays of objects and display components on site?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create card components and map through my data file to display them, which I managed to do with one array object data file. But my problem occurs if I want to reuse the card component with a new array data file, I can't seem to get the data.

So data example

```
 export const data1 = [
  {
   title: 'first',
   desc: 'first desc,
   img: 'image-1.jpg'
  },
  {
   title: 'second',
   desc: 'second desc,
   img: 'image-2.jpg'
  },
 ]
```

So if I only have one data array, I just map through it like this

```
 {data1.map((data, index) => {
  return (
 <Title>{data.title}</Title>
 <Desc>{data.desc}</Desc>
 <Img src={data.img} />
 )
 })
```

Then if I wanna display this card component, I would just add it to my page

```
 <CardComponent />
```

But now if I wanna reuse this component and just switch out the data, I can't map through it properly because it's only mapping through the data1 array.

So if I make another array

```
 export const dataTwo = [
  {
   title: 'third',
   desc: 'third desc,
   img: 'image-3.jpg'
  },
  {
   title: 'fourth',
   desc: 'fourth desc,
   img: 'image-4.jpg'
  },
 ]
```

Now I can't reuse my component because the map() is only targeting data1.map and not dataTwo.map

So I'm not sure exactly how I'd create essentially a new Card component

Ideally, I'd want this result

```
 <Navbar />
 <CardComponent {...data1} />
 <MainSection>
 <CardComponent {...dataTwo} />
 <Footer />
```

But the issue is I am mapping through the values instead of just getting data from a regular object, so this method doesn't work.

Any idea how I would implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the arrays as a prop to `CardComponent`, such as a `data` prop.

```
<CardComponent data={data1} />
...
<CardComponent data={dataTwo} />
```

And map the passed `data` prop in `CardComponent`. Remember that the mapping needs to return everything wrapped in a single node (i.e. `div`, `Fragment`, etc..) and should have an attached react key.

Example

```
const CardComponent = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <Title>{data.title}</Title>
            <Desc>{data.desc}</Desc>
            <Img src={data.img} />
          </Fragment>
        );
     })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple arrays that you want to be displayed, you can flatten them together into one when calling the component, eg:

```
<CardComponent data={data1.concat(dataTwo)} />
```

```
props.data.map((item) => (
    <Title>{item.title}</Title>
    <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
    <Img src={item.img} />
))
```